# BulletSpan not working in Android Textview

Tags: android, html, textview, bullet-span

I'm trying to add bullets to the `unordered` lists using `BulletSpan.` But, I cannot find bullets in the list. Below is my code:

```
private static String appendBullet(int leadingMargin, String liText) {
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(liText);
    spannableString.setSpan(new BulletSpan(leadingMargin), 0, liText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    Log.d("Ul tags", String.valueOf(spannableString));
    return spannableString.toString();
}
```

Here `liItext` is the list item. I'm adding a `BulletSpan` here and then returning the item and adding it to the `list` and finally adding the entire list to the `StringBuilder`.

```
liList.add(appendBullet(15, liText));

List<String> liList = addListWithBullets(lists, new ArrayList<String>());

if (liList.size() > 0) {
    for (String str : liList) {
        builder.append(str);
        builder.append("<br/>");
    }
    Log.d("Ul tags", String.valueOf(liList));
}
```

Comment: return `CharSequence` from `appendBullet`, not a `String`

Comment: But I'm adding bullets to a list and the list can contain string items too

Comment: I tried returning a charsequence..Still it's not working

Comment: see http://codeshare.io/6oRt9

Comment: No..It's not working..When I add it inside the custom textview, it works. But in Utility class, it's not working.

Comment: i have no idea what utility class you are talking about, and in my code i don't use any custom view,  just ordinary TextView

Comment: @SangeethaPinto what is your utility class. Could you please provide little bit more info

Answer (score 0):

First of all you probably want to use `SpannableStringBuilder` instead of `StringBuilder`. Secondly, in your `appendBullet(...)` method by calling `toString()` on the `SpannableString` instance you're probably losing all of the spanning information! What you probably want to do instead is append each `String` which is to be bulleted to the `SpannableStringBuilder` instance and then call the `setSpan(...)` method on the `SpannableStringBuilder` instance for each of these `String`s.

If it helps I've put together an extension function on the `SpannableStringBuilder` class which takes away some of this difficulty for you. You can find [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-utils/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/tazkiyatech/utils/display/SpannableStringBuilders.kt).